# как перебрать все значения столбца в таблице базы данных в django?

Tags: sql, python-3.x, django

есть вот такая модель:

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, db_index = True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=400, unique = True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=30, db_index = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

мне нужно перебрать все значения name и password из таблицы баз данных, чтобы сверить их с введёнными пользователем никнеймом и паролем. Как это сделать с помощью Django и можно ли обойтись без SQL?

Comment: Надеюсь, вы понимаете, что хранить пароль в базе в открытом виде - это ужасная идея. И не совсем понятно, зачем вам вручную делать выборку и сравнивать пароли, если у Django из коробки есть удобная и функциональная система аутентификации, в которой всё это уже реализовано в лучшем видел.

Comment: мне хотелось дать возможность вводить любой пароль и ник с любыми символами

Comment: но в ней нельзя вводить email

Comment: Можно. И любые ограничения на символы можно снять, и email вместо username использовать можно.

Comment: но как это сделать?

Comment: [Здесь](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/passwords/#module-django.contrib.auth.password_validation) описано, как устанавливать ограничения на пароль. [Здесь](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) описано, как можно изменить ограничения на имя пользователя. А [здесь](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend) способ, который позволит использовать email вместо имени пользователя при логине.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
name = 'admin'
password = 'qwerty'

user = User.objects.get(name=name)
if user.password == password:
    print('Пароли совпадают')
```